# VM gone after hard reboot

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, esxi

I have a serious problem here. After I forced a reboot of a freezed ESXi server, a VM is literally gone. When I ssh to the host and run `ls -lah` inside the datastore, it returnes:

```
/vmfs/volumes/51193143-2de76e36-d365-001b21b87f7c # ls -lah
ls: ./MISSING-VM: No such file or directory
drwxr-xr-t    1 root     root         2.6k Sep  8  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          512 Apr 30 00:23 ..
-r--------    1 root     root         3.6M Feb 11  2013 .fbb.sf
-r--------    1 root     root        60.2M Feb 11  2013 .fdc.sf
-r--------    1 root     root       243.8M Feb 11  2013 .pbc.sf
-r--------    1 root     root       248.3M Feb 11  2013 .sbc.sf
-r--------    1 root     root         4.0M Feb 11  2013 .vh.sf
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          560 Jan  2 13:16 vm1
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         1.5k Apr 29 23:07 vm2
```

`echo *` lists the MISSING-VM directory!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried checking the filesystem?